# Upload field point to CD/DVD ROM instead of HDD [PHP]

Tags: php, file-upload, cddvd

I have built a project for my client in which patients register themselves from the frontend. While they register, they can upload their medical records (pdf, doc, jpg) etc. Now I need to provide them facility to upload "DICOM" files as well which i can do in a manner as i did for above file types. But the real problem here is that DICOM files reside in CD/DVD disc (medical consultants do like this) and this data can not be transferred from CD/DVD ROM on local disk (HDD) so that he can upload it using normal file upload field.

Now my question is that:

1. Is there any way to point normal upload field to CD/DVD-ROM so that user can select his DICOM files from CD/DVD-ROM and then upload?
2. Is there any possibility to create an option for making an ISO image of the currently mounted CD/DVD-ROM, save it on HDD and then upload that ISO file through normal upload field?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have inserted any Data CD/Disk in your CD rom. You will not see the icon for CD-ROM on Upload field click if there is no any CD in your CD-ROM.

Hope this helps